# Standard/Common location for cross compilation toolchain

Tags: cross-compilation, root-filesystem, buildroot

Does a standard or common location exist for installing cross compilation tools? I can easily pick my own location and it works fine, so I'm just looking to find the most ideal location.

Based on [this post](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/) I'm currently considering something like `/opt/cross-tools`.

Any problems using that location? Should I just put it under `/usr`? For reference, the "tools" come from the output of [buildroot](http://buildroot.org/).

Comment: I do not know if standard but from personal experience, `/opt` and `/soft` are oft used locations for cross-compilation tools.

Comment: In my search for answers, this has become a useful resource: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard